# Clear redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component `PostsShow` which is showing the selected post:

```
@connect((state) => ({post: state.posts.post}), {fetchPost})    
class PostsShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    if (!post) {
      return <div></div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <h6>Categories: {post.categories}</h6>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when user first visits the page, `fetchPost` function populates state section (`posts.post`) with some data associated with chosen post and when the user chooses another post, he can see old data for 1-2 sec. (before new request is finished).

Actions map:

1. Click on post #1
2. Click `Back` button
3. Click on post #2
4. For 1 sec. you can see old (#1) post, until the request is finished and component refreshed with the post (#2) data.

I'm new to whole redux concept, so i'm curious how are you avoiding this kind of behavior?

**MY SOLUTION:**

I assume that you can create a switch branch, which will modify sate with (`posts.post` part) with `null` value and trigger this behavior on `componentWillUnmount` method. So:

**Action:**

```
export function clearPost() {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_POST,
    payload: null
  }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], post: null };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ... Other cases

    case CLEAR_POST:
      return { ...state, post: null }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
class PostsShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearPost();
  }

  render() {
    // Old render
  }
}
```

Is this a good approach for react with redux?

Comment: Shouldn't be `state.posts` an array or an object mapping the post id to the actual post? Your problem is, that `state.posts.post` is still there after from your last fetch.

Comment: @trixn , Yes, but i don't see why is that a problem? Seems to me like a common approach for this kind of goals...or maybe i misunderstood your question?

Comment: `state.posts.post` makes no sense to me. Why has an object called `posts` a property named `post`. It should be an array of posts or a map of post id's to post objects. This way a new post with another id will render as an empty div if you connect your component to get it from state by post id.

Comment: @trixn state.posts is an object with 2 props. - `all: [], post: null`. Prop. `all` stands for an array of all posts and `post` for currently fetched post with all the details (typically, if you want to get a description and all the details, you need to make another request with `id` of the post).

Comment: i would trigger another action creator, something like: `{type: 'fetching_start'}` and will show a loader instead of the `post` data. when the data is ready i would trigger another action creator `{type: 'fetching_end'}` to hide the loader and show the data. this is a common pattern.

Comment: @Sagivb.g can you provide some example? I’m a little bit confused with this approach

Comment: Just to be clear here, you want to hide the data when when you fetch for new data right? so you are asking how to clear the state so nothing will be shown on the screen until you get new data. is this correct?

Comment: @Sagivb.g correct. And it will be great if you can explain, why is that approach is better than the one, that i described in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state structure is not ideal. Try keeping your posts like that:

```
posts: {
    byID: {
        1: {/*the post* no 1/},
        2: {/*the post* no 2/},
        // ...
    }
    allIDs: [2, 1 /*, ...*/],
}
```

This way you can provide an ordered list of post id's for a list view and show a single post by getting it from the state like: `this.posts.byID['thePostID']`.

Also read up in the redux docs on [how to normalize state](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html).

This will also fix your problem because when your get your post from the store with an id that does not already exist, it will be `undefined` thus rendering as an empty `div`. A loading indicator would be the best thing to show.

Comment: You got me worng. You can't get all the info about post with only 1 request. The list of all posts contains only `title` and `id`. In order to get a description (which is needed for viewing the post) you need to make ANOTHER request. So, the result of that request is stored in a separate property of the `posts` object called `post`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Your `posts` endpoint should answer with at least the post id and maybe other info like a title. But you have to store your post data inside the post object then. You can easily fetch additional (missing) information for that post later and store that in the same post object. I don't see a problem with that. It's important to normalize your state or you will run into multiple of those problems you already have.

Comment: Okay and why not show the information you already have (title) and only fetch the missing data then? You should really read the redux docs section i linked in my answer.

Comment: "So, the result of that request is stored in a separate property of the posts object called post". This is your problem here. It should not be stored in another object. This violates the "single source of truth" principle. It should be in the same object that already has the title of the post with this id. There should never be multiple objects holding the same information.

Comment: So, basically I need to fetch only description for each post and before fetching provide a check for already existing description in the post object ?

Comment: Yeah that would be a better approach. You could still fetch everything for that post and override the data you already have in case they changed in the mean time if that can happen in your case. Anyways it wouldn't be harmful. The main thing is not having multiple parts of your post spread all over your store. It is best practice to keep everything for a particular post in one object and only update this one object.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I thought that this is a common problem (maybe because the application was built according to the bought react course), but now it seems to me that when you have a good `state` tree design, you seem not to receive such a problems in you app at all. I will try to do my best and improve my knowladge in that area. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making an async call , which takes time to get new date, that is why when fetch posts gets new data then your component will update and render it. 
You can have two approaches:
1) you can create a an async function which will  dispatch an action that will have a update the reducer with payload as

```
status :LOADING,
```

once the fetch function returns with new data again dispatch an action that 
will update the reducer as

```
status:SUCCESS
```

and in your component check if status received in the props by store is 'LOADING' or 'SUCCESS', if SUCCESS then show new state, if LOADING keep showing some text like component is Loading:

here is the example

SomeComponent.js

```
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.model = {}
     }
  render () {
    const {
      status
    } = this.props
    const loading = status === 'LOADING'

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Row>
               <FormField
                  label='First Name'
                  id='first-name'
                  value={details.firstName}
                  onChange={this.update('firstName’)}
                  disabled={loading}
                  mandatory
                />
        </Row>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
const fetchDetails = (someId) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(dataFetching())
    return http.get(dispatch, `https//someCall`, null, {
      'Accept': SOME_HEADER
    }).then((data) => {
        dispatch(dataFetched(data))
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(someError(`Unable to retrieve the details ${error}`))
    })
  }
}

const dataFetching = () => ({
  type: constants.DATA_FETCHING
})
const dataFetched = (data) => ({
  type: constants.DATA_FETCHED,
  data
})
```

Reducer.js

```
  export default function reducer (state = {}, action = {}) {
      switch (action.type) {

        case constants.DATA_FETCHING:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            data: {},
            status: 'LOADING'
          })
        case constants.DATA_FETCHED:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            data: action.data,
            status: 'SUCCESS'
          })

        default:
          return state
      }

}
```

2nd Approach 
 The one which you did, but for clarity try to use the first one.